# A question about finitely additive extensions of Lebesgue measure

Tags: set-theory, measure-theory

Suppose $m:P([0, 1]) \to [0, 1]$ is a finitely additive measure extending the Lebesgue measure. Must there exist some $X \subseteq [0, 1]$ such that $m(X \cap I) = |I|/2$ for every sub interval $I \subseteq [0, 1]$?

Comment: is it known whether such an $X$ exists for the usual Lebesgue measure itself?

Comment: @Mirko: No such $X$ can be Lebesgue measurable because of Lebesgue Density Theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_density_theorem

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais Doesn't your comment answer the question negatively (given the Lebesgue measure could be thought of as an "extension" of itself)? Namely we need $m(X)=m(X\cap[0,1])=\dfrac12$, but $X$ is not measurable. Well, I just realized the extension is supposed to be defined for every subset of $[0,1]$ (so $X$ would be measurable too).

Comment: Hi Mirko, If m accidentally happens to be countably additive, then there is such a set. See the second paragraph on page 84: http://www.math.wisc.edu/~akumar/IND_IDEALS.pdf

Comment: If $m$ is isometry-invariant then you can take $X$ to be "every other real number". See Terry Tao's post here: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/10/14/non-measurable-sets-via-non-standard-analysis/

Comment: @SeanEberhard Thanks! Do you see, say under CH, a way to construct some non isometry-invariant counterexample via Hahn-Banach?

Comment: @Ashutosh It's a charming question. Intuitively (but completely nonrigorously) if you just choose $X$ at random by including every $x$ in $X$ independently with probability $1/2$ then $X$ almost surely works. Could it be true more generally of every finitely additive measure without atoms?